# Sum up two columns using a trigger in mysql and Find the percentage

Tags: mysql

[image: Sample Of MY table]## HOW TO SUM UP AND FIND PERCENTAGE TWO COLUMNS IN MYSQL USING A TRIGGER  ##
I have tried creating a trigger to sum up two of my columns using the SUM function in mysql.Trigger is created successfully but upon data inserting i found out that the trigger is not working.Kindly help me out.

```
CREATE TRIGGER StudentPopulation 
BEFORE INSERT ON studentable
FOR EACH ROW 
   SET NEW.total = ((NEW.`NUMBER_OF_MALES`)/(SUM(NEW.`NUMBER_OF_MALES`)+ SUM(NEW.`NUMBER_OF_FEMALES`))) * 100;
```

Comment: Help us help you - share your trigger

Comment: Please provide a short sample of data, plus what you expect the result to be.

Comment: @Rick so what i want to achieve is to get the sum of the entire column of Num_of_male displayed in Total and the Sum of Num_Of_Female also in another column like Total 2 and also with their respective percentages in seperate columns

Comment: @joe - Are you trying to sum up 15+15+15?  Are you inserting another row with 15 and 4, then wanting the trigger to compute 15+4?  Where are percentages in the example?  Sorry, but your question is still unclear.

Comment: @ Rick James Exactly that. Sorry i left other columns like total for females and percentage for males and females because i removed them long time ago. The First Total you see in the picture is for males, there is another for females.With the above image, Total for male should become 45 and total for female should become 12 in row 2 that is the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Since MySQL 5.7.5 you don't need a trigger - you can use a generated column where you just provide the expression and leave all the heavy lifting to the database:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    col_a INT,
    col_b INT,
    sum_a_b INT AS (col_a + col_b)
);
```

Comment: I am trying to sum up two columns. This code only sums up the row

Comment: That is what i am trying to do, I have edited the post with my code

Answer (score 0):

Don't recompute every time a student signs up for a class.  Instead, compute the ratio in the `SELECT` statement you eventually run.

If you don't like any of the answers so far, then you need to better explain what is in `studentable`.

SUM(NEW.`NUMBER_OF_MALES`) sounds like there are multiple rows.  One row per class?  Or what?

Do you want the %male in each class?  In which case you don't need `SUM`.

Etc.

Comment: I have multiple rows. What i am trying to achieve is the sum of each column displayed as total and the percentage of each column displayed as percentage for every record a user inserts into the table.Currently mysql is not able to autocompute the sum for each column but rather each row.